# Running `xattr -rc` Swift runtime produces No such file when within Application Support folder. Running from terminal works fine

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, shell

`xattr -rc "/Users/Me/Library/Containers/BundleId/Data/Library/Application Support/BundleId/Game.app": No such file or directory`

---

`Game.app` wont open normally since it was downloaded and unzipped from the `Launcher.app` and Apple doesn't like that very much.

Both apps have been codesigned and notorized.

I'm storing the downloaded `Game.zip` and the unzipped `Game.app` using the Application Support directory.

```
FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory,
                        in: .userDomainMask,
                        appropriateFor: nil,
                        create: true)
    .appendingPathComponent(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, isDirectory: true)
```

Running this code to try and strip the attributes:

```
    @discardableResult
    private func shell() -> Int32 {
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
        task.arguments = "xattr -rc \"\(self.gameExe.path)\""
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
        return task.terminationStatus
    }
```

I've tried using `chmod -R 755 \"\(self.gameExe.path)\"` and it worked (ie. found the file and ran the command) but it still wouldnt open the `Game.app` thats why Im trying `xattr` instead.

Cant figure out why chmod "worked" but xattr isnt working.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process) `task.launchPath` and `task.launch()` is "Deprecated" and not recommended to use any more. Instead use `task.executableURL` and `try task.run()`. 
Besides, it's not the best way to run chmod or xattr with Process. 
Therefore swift has an own method. You can modify any file attribute using the Attribute keys.
rather use:

```swift
   do {
    
   var attributes = [FileAttributeKey : Any]()
   attributes[.posixPermissions] = 0o755 // number as octal
    
   try FileManager.default.setAttributes(attributes, ofItemAtPath: "yourPath")
    
   } catch { return false  }
```

You can easily check whether your file is executable by using:

```swift
let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: "yourPath")

do {

   let isExec = try path.resourceValues(forKeys:  [.isExecutableKey]).isExecutable //returns true or false
   
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
   
}
```

I hope this might help you.